# Does using boost pointers change your OO design methodology?

Tags: c++, boost, oop

After switching from C++ to C++ w/boost, do you think your OOD skills improved?

Do you notice patterns in "Normal" C++ code that you wouldn't consider that you've switched, or do you find that it enables a more abstract design?

I guess I'm really wondering if you just use it as a tool, or if you change your entire approach to OO design to make more efficient use of objects when using boost pointers.

Edit:summary

This question was kind of strange--I was asking because I've run into so much C++ code that was not at all OO.  I'm fairly sure (with that and my work on it before moving to a managed language) that it's harder to think in OO in C++ than a managed language.

From looking at these posts, I'm guessing that you learn the value of OO before finding a need for a better way to manage memory, so by the time you start looking for something like Boost,  you're already using OO methodologies pretty heavily.

I was kind of expecting a bunch of answers saying that it helped them think in OO, but now that I think about it, if you aren't using OO, boost pointers are not very helpful, and you wouldn't see the need for them (so you wouldn't have replied).

Comment: Clearly, Boost smart pointers are useful, but they're not revolutionary for design ! Are you considering Boost libraries as a whole in your question, or just smart pointers ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a project in C++ I was doing about six years ago, we implemented our own boost-like automatic pointer scheme.  It worked pretty well, except for the various bugs in it.  (Sure wish we had used boost...)

Nonetheless, it really didn't change how we developed code.  Object oriented design, with or without managed pointers, is very similar.  There's times when you need to return objects, or times when pointers to objects are more important.  The nice thing about smart pointers has only a small amount to do with how you design your application.  Instead of passing a potentially dangerous memory leak around, you can pass that same data and be fairly certain that it's not going to leak.

In that respect, there are some things you can tend to do more with smart pointers: simplify your code.  Instead of returning integers or basic structures every where, you can more freely pass complicated data structures or classes without worry.  You can build more complex apps, faster, without having to worry so much.  It lets you have the raw power of C and C++ when you need it (why would you be using C or C++ if you didn't need it?) and have the ease of memory management that's such an amazing productivity boost.  If automatically managed memory wasn't useful, it wouldn't be in almost every other language on the planet!

Comment: Since there is no correct answer to this (Subjective), I'm just selecting yours as the highest voted.  The answers gave me the perspective I needed though, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

STL/Boost is a tool for the job. They help me implement my ideas not the other way around. Clarification: Boost did not boost up my OOD skills.

Comment: Modded down for ...? Isn't this a 'what do you make of it' question where my subjective opinion is asked for and there are no correct answers as such?

Comment: Not the voter, but I'd guess the downvote was because you didn't really answer the question directly. The question as I see it is, "Have you changed the way you work by using Boost?" Your answer, "They help me implement my ideas," could mean that you work differently now or it could mean nothing.

Answer (score 3):

It has deeply changed my way of coding, and i'm spreading the word. Through the use of Boost.Graph and Boost.PropertyMap in particular, i realized that i could write "true" algorithms in a simple class, not (yet) knowing how to access information, not even knowing (or caring) what sub-actions might be done while executing the algorithm.
My team is now designing complex computing functionality using a graphical tool.

One might argue that templates are really the base of this change, but Boost clearly paved the way. To me, discovering new Boost libraries is very often a great opportunity to learn important stuff that can be applied to our everyday work !

Answer (score 1):

Once I discovered `boost::bind` (and `boost::function`) I found instead of thinking in terms of inheritance and abstract base classes ("interfaces" in java/c#-speak) I started seeing everything as a functor.

For example, pre-boost I'd have built a menu system where the menus were containers of `IActionable*` items and anything which wanted to be hooked into the menu system would have to inherit IActionable and provide an action method.  Post-boost and I'm implementing menus containing `boost::function<void()>` objects and just throwing anything I want into them using `boost::bind`.

Another thing: just looking at the way in which boost successfully employs templates really made me raise my expectations of what was possible with them and make the effort to make better use of them in my own code, so I'm writing a lot more "generic" and less "OOP" code.

The smart pointers are certainly useful and get a lot of coverage, but apart from cleaning up some explicit deletes they're hardly a paradigm shift.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it didn't change the way I do design, but Boost does give me additional tools so that certain things are easier. For example, with "smart" pointers, I no longer have to think about making sure certain object creations have to destroyed at the proper time (mostly in the exceptional case). But like any tool, I have to understand when to use them and when NOT to.